# Update dict em List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho alguns dicionários que preciso preencher recursivamente e para isso gostaria de usar list comprehensions desta forma

```
list_dict = [{'a':'b'},{'a':'c'}]

list_dict = [dict.update({'b':dict['a']}) for dict in list_dict]
```

O objetivo era trabalhar com datetime onde eu adicionaria um valor a cada dicionario.

O problema é que ao utilizar dict.update() ele retorna None ao invés do valor do dicionário o que me devolve mais ou menos isso:

```
[None,None]
```

Tentei utilizar também um map() desta forma:

```
list(map(lambda dict: dict.update({'novo_valor':100}),list_dict))
```

Porém recebi o mesmo retorno.

Tentei algumas outras coisas como utilizar and dentro do list comprehension mas sem sucesso.

Alguém tem algum idéia que possa ajudar.

Exemplo pratico:

```
MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE = 15
MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION = 30
Entrada = {
        'UserName':'user.1',
        'AccessKeyId':'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
        'Status':'Inactive',
     'CreateDate':datetime.datetime(2019,9,10,20,12,45,tzinfo=tzutc())
    },
    {
        'UserName':'user.2',
        'AccessKeyId':'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
        'Status':'Active',
      'CreateDate':datetime.datetime(2020,4,16,1,26,18,tzinfo=tzutc())
    }
]
```

Função que criei:

```
def add_date_paramters(complete_access_key_list):
    key_list = list()
    for acess_key in complete_access_key_list:
        acess_key.update(
            {
                'InvalidationDate':acess_key['CreateDate']+datetime.timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE),
                'ExpirationDate':acess_key['CreateDate']+datetime.timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION),
            }
        )
        key_list.append(acess_key)
    return key_list
```

Espero ter algo parecido com isso:

```
saida = [ {
        'UserName':'user.1',
        'AccessKeyId':'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
        'Status':'Inactive',
        'CreateDate':datetime.datetime(2019,9,10,20,12,45,tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'InvalidationDate':datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 20, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'ExpirationDate':datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10, 20, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzutc())
    },
    {
        'UserName':'user.2',
        'AccessKeyId':'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
        'Status':'Active',
        'CreateDate':datetime.datetime(2020,4,16,1,26,18,tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'InvalidationDate':datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 1, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'ExpirationDate':datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 16, 1, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
    }, ]
```

Comment: Você tem ao menos um exemplo prático com uma entrada e a saída esperada ?

Comment: desculpe não pude responder tudo aqui, completei na pergunta

Comment: @Lacobus Obrigado consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução básica na qual a lista de dicionarios é atualizada *in-place*:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE = 15
MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION = 30

list_dict = [
    {
        'UserName'   : 'user.1',
        'AccessKeyId': 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
        'Status'     : 'Inactive',
        'CreateDate' : datetime(2019,9,10,20,12,45,tzinfo=tzutc())
    },
    {
        'UserName'   : 'user.2',
        'AccessKeyId': 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
        'Status'     : 'Active',
        'CreateDate' : datetime(2020,4,16,1,26,18,tzinfo=tzutc())
    }
]

for dic in list_dict:
    dic['InvalidationDate'] = dic['CreateDate'] + timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE)
    dic['ExpirationDate'] = dic['CreateDate'] + timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION)

print(list_dict)
```

Saída:

```
[
  {
    'UserName': 'user.1',
    'AccessKeyId': 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
    'Status': 'Inactive',
    'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 10, 20, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    'InvalidationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 20, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    'ExpirationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10, 20, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzutc())
  },
  {
    'UserName': 'user.2',
    'AccessKeyId': 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',
    'Status': 'Active',
    'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 16, 1, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    'InvalidationDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 1, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    'ExpirationDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 16, 1, 26, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
  }
]
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/VillainousStrongAssociate)

Encapsulando em uma função:

```
def add_date_parameters(lst):
    for dic in lst:
        dic.update({
            'InvalidationDate': dic['CreateDate'] + timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE),
            'ExpirationDate'  : dic['CreateDate'] + timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION)
        })
    return lst
```

Comment: Crie os testes unitários para as duas funções e realmente sua forma é mais performática. 
1.000.000 de requisições a função obtive os seguintes resultados.
feito um teste de stress com 
=== 1 passed, 1 warning in 8.28s ===
contra:
===1 passed, 1 warning in 15.78s ===
Para poucas requisições costuma ficar perto de 0.50.

Sempre ouvi que esses map() filter() e comprehension eram mais performáticos, essa diferença se da por que estou aplicando errado ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 0):

Liguei para um amigo e expliquei o caso.

Ele me sugeriu utiliza o operado `or` para quando o `dict.update()` retornar `None` a expressão considerar o retorno como o que vem depois:

solução:

```
def add_date_paramters(complete_access_key_list):
    return map( lambda acess_key: acess_key.update(
        {
            'InvalidationDate':acess_key['CreateDate']+datetime.timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_INACTIVE),
            'ExpirationDate':acess_key['CreateDate']+datetime.timedelta(days=MAX_DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION)
        }
    ) or acess_key ,complete_access_key_list)
```

Meu erro foi tentar utilizar o `and` que acabava sendo falso na primeira verificação e não retornava nada. 
Agradeço a atenção.